# Scrollto on specific page of my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, scrollto

Sorry for my bad english.
I'm a beginner in web development and I'm actually in the process of constructing my site.
I'm stuck in a specific function.

I would like to make a button in the index, which redirects to the bottom of a specific page/url of my site.

I think jQuery is the solution to combine these two functions (a href, scrollTo) but I don't know how to do that.

To summarize, after loading my page, the window is placed directly at the bottom of it.

Comment: you can start to learn for example: [how-to-link-to-specific-points-in-a-page-and-animate-the-scroll](http://designshack.net/articles/html/how-to-link-to-specific-points-in-a-page-and-animate-the-scroll/)

Comment: Scroll to div is it???

Answer (score -1):

try below script:

```
$('#DIVID')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

If its div at the bottom then you can try this

```
  goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));
```

I have a demo for you [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/VPzxG/1567/)